# Обрезать див внутри дива

Tags: html, css

Всем доброго вечера

```
<div style="width:198px;height:198px;">
    <div style="width:200px;height:200px;">
    </div>
</div>
```

Есть 2 дива, 1й, и внутри него 2й. Можно ли сделать так, что бы первый не растягивался, в зависимости от размеров второго, что бы там ни было? А второй был ровно по центру первого, если не влезал в него?

т.е. допустим если я туда (в второй) положу какой ни будь скрипт, который картинку генерирует, и он в итоге сделает картинку 200x200, то, что бы 1й див, размер которого 198x198, отрезал от внутреннего по 1 пикселю с каждой из 4х сторон. Или если табличку у которой border=1 200х200 поместить в 1й див, то в итоге border не будет виден.

p.s. спросил немного пере мудрено. Вообщем, нужно обрезание внутреннего дива. Прошу не предлагать бакграунд позишон, т.к. в диве может быть не только картинка

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте CSS-свойство [oferflow: hidden](http://htmlbook.ru/css/overflow) для внешнего дива.

Comment: Эм.. Вообще-то содержимое от этого центрироваться не начнёт.

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант, первому диву поставить overflow: hidden. А внутреннему position: relative и через left, top его смещать. 
left = top = (200 - 198) / 2

Вместо 198 и 200 могут быть переменные JS